# using AVG aggregate function in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have one "orders" table:

```
ID  CustomerID  Freight
1      VINET      32.38
2      TOMPS      11.61
.        .          .
.        .          . 
.        .          .
```

I want to select just those customerID s that have freight more than average!!

```
SELECT CustomerID FROM Orders WHERE CustomerID IN(SELECT CustomerID,AVG(Freight) AVGFreight FROM Orders Group By CustomerID )
```

I know till here but  how can I compare freight with the average!?? please help me thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that a customer will have 1 record each.

<strike>SELECT CustomerID
    FROM dbo.Orders 
    WHERE Freight >= (SELECT @AvgFreight = AVG(Freight) FROM dbo.Orders)</strike>

I am not sure, if this will work. Try it.
Upvote @marc_s's answer, as I am basing it off his reply.

```
SELECT CustomerID
FROM dbo.Orders 
WHERE AVG(Freight) >= (SELECT AVG(Freight) FROM dbo.Orders)
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

Comment: Please explain what you are looking for, with sample input as well as output data.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT CustomerID 
FROM dbo.Orders 
WHERE Freight >= (SELECT AVG(Freight) FROM dbo.Orders)
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

You select your customers, all of which have a freight cost which is larger than the average of all freight costs in the table.

Comment: I should just select the Customer ID

Comment: aha this one will find the avarage of each customerID and then will check the freight of each customer ID with its average?

Comment: @Matin1234: it will calculate the average freight over all entries of the table - then select all customers which have a freight value higher than that average

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Orders(
    ID int,
    CustomerId varchar(10),
    Freight money
);
INSERT INTO Orders Values(1,'VINET',10);
INSERT INTO Orders values(2,'VINET',10);
INSERT INTO Orders values(3,'TOMPS',12);
INSERT INTO Orders values(4,'TOMPS',11);
```

Display average:

```
Select CustomerId,avg(Freight)AvgFreight
from Orders
group by customerId
```

`| CustomerId | AvgFreight |
|------------+------------|
| TOMPS      |      11.50 |
| VINET      |      10.00 |
|------------+------------|`

Compare freight with the average:

```
Select Orders.CustomerId 
from Orders,
(Select CustomerId,avg(Freight)AvgFreight
from Orders
Group by customerId)t
Where Orders.Freight > t.AvgFreight
And Orders.CustomerId = t.Customerid
```

`| CustomerId |
|------------|
| TOMPS      |
|------------|`

Answer (score 0):

Using `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT CustomerID
FROM Orders 
GROUP BY CustomerID 
HAVING AVG(Freight) > (SELECT AVG(Freight) FROM Orders)
```